# Representation of conjugate directions

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a way to represent conjugate directions on a Mohr circle of curvature?

( Surface Theory, Second fundamental form, M = 0 )

Directions given by double angles AOB, AOC. Is this attempt correct?

[image: Conj Dirns Mohr]